# Compute the expected value of the product between a Lebesgue–Stieltjes type integral and an Ito integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Hi, I have the following expected value to compute

$E[ \int_{o}^{T} f(t) dt \int_{o}^{T} H(s) dW(s)]$,

where $f(t)$ and $H(s)$ are two stochastic processes adapted to the filtration generated by the Brownian motion W.

I think that this expected value could be equal to zero, but I really don't know how to give this proof.

Thank you in advance for any kind of advice or references.

Imma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write $h(s)=\int_0^Tf(t)dtH(s)$ then your expectation could be written as $E[ \int_{o}^{T} h(s) dW(s)]$. This integral is $0$ if you can prove $(\int_{o}^{t} h(s) dW(s)) $ to be a martingale, for example $E(\int_{o}^{T} h^2(s) ds)<+\infty$.

As you noticed in your comment, this procedure is correct if we can suppose that the process $h(s)$ is adapted, which is the case if $f$ is deterministic. Otherwise we can the decompose the integral as the in the following

$$\int_0^T(\int_0^Tf(t)dt)H(s)dW_s =\int_0^T(\int_0^sf(t)dt)H(s)dW_s+\int_0^T(\int_s^Tf(t)dt)H(s)dW_s$$

then with interverting of the order of integration in the second integral we can write
$$\int_0^T(\int_s^Tf(t)dt)H(s)dW_s=\int_0^T(\int_0^tH(s)dW_s)f(t)dt$$

The process apperaing in the integrals are now adapted, and you can add the condition so that Fubini works and to justify the martangality of the integrals. Hope thsi help.

Comment: If $f(t)$ is a deterministic function this procedure works.
In this case, I'm not completely sure!
Because I don't know how to prove that $h(s)$ is adapted to the filtration generated by the Brownian motion.

Thank you for your help!!



Comment: I edited the first answer to take into account your comment


Comment: Thank you.....I think this is the right way to proceed.
Definitely, this expected value cannot be zero.